# PHP - remove entire line in subtitle that contain with specific word

Tags: php, regex, subtitle

I have sets of specific words that i want to detect them in subtitle and then remove entire line with regex:

```php
$forbiddenWords = [
    'Ads',
    'Download',
    //
];

$file = file_get_contents('example.srt');

foreach ($forbiddenWords as $word) {
    $file .= preg_replace("/\d{3}(?!.*?-)[\s\S]*?$word\[\s\S]*?(?=\d)/", '', $file);
}
```

Lines of subtitle:

```
1
00:00:39,243 --> 00:00:45,820
This line is ok

2
00:00:46,243 --> 00:00:51,820
This line with
"Ads" word should be deleted
and next line

3
00:01:04,243 --> 00:01:05,820
This line with
"Download" word should be deleted
and next line

4
00:01:08,664 --> 00:01:12,331
An ok line
```

The output i want :

```
1
00:00:39,243 --> 00:00:45,820
This line is ok

2
00:00:46,243 --> 00:00:51,820


3
00:01:04,243 --> 00:01:05,820


4
00:01:08,664 --> 00:01:12,331
An ok line
```

My regex doesn't work and it captures multiple lines [DEMO REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fwyY0p/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~^(\d+\R(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (?2))(?:\R(?!(?1)).*)*?\b(?:Download|Ads)\b[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:(?1)|\z))~mu', '$1', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IFnZqC/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(\d+\R(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (?2))` - Group 1 (the subtitle ID + timespan line):

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\R` - a line break char sequence
  - `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})` - Group 2 (timestamp): 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, comma, three digits
  - `-->`  - literal string
  - `(?2)` - timestamp pattern
- `(?:\R(?!(?1)).*)*?` - any 0 or more (but as few as possible) lines that do not start with the subtitle ID + timespan pattern
- `\b(?:Download|Ads)\b` - whole word `Download` or `Ads` (add more if you need)
- `[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:(?1)|\z))` - any 0 or more chars as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of 0+ whitespaces followed with timespan pattern or end of the whole string.

Comment: Thanks it worked, But one thing, Sometimes i need detect arabic/persian words, For example if  the detected word was "ایمان" it doesnt capture the line, https://regex101.com/r/xVFlfd/1

Comment: @Mwthreex Add `u` after `~m`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVFlfd/2). I added the flag to the code in the answer.

Comment: could you add php side also? The regex works but i couldnt replace it with nothing: 

preg_replace("/yourRegex/u", '$1', $file);

Comment: @Mwthreex PHP code is aready in the answer. You forgot to use `m` flag. `$text= preg_replace('~^(\d+\R(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (?2))(?:\R(?!(?1)).*)*?\b(?:Download|Ads)\b[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:(?1)|\z))~mu', '$1', $text)
`

Comment: I found the problem, When i read the with file_get_content it have \r\n in entire subtitle i dumped the result look https://i.imgur.com/J5vrg6C.png, So what should i do now?

Comment: @Mwthreex `\R` matches any line break sequence, CR, LF, CRLF... It should work. If you have literal 2-char combinations in the file (`'\\r\\n'` in PHP string literal), you will have to add them to the regex, `$text= preg_replace('~^(\d+\\\\r\\\\n\R(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (?2)\\\\r\\\\n)(?:\R(?!(?1)).*)*?\b(?:Download|Ads)\b[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:(?1)|\z))~mu', '$1', $text)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVFlfd/3).

Comment: Please run this script and see the result: https://paiza.io/projects/7-6IvtvX0On06bll-1jhog

The srt file is within the file_get_content function you can test it in your own os

Comment: @Mwthreex Why did you remove all backslashes in the regex? Please use the code in my answer.

Comment: God bless you it was working, But it seems it doesnt capture domain name, for example: if the line has www.Domain.com,  it doesnt detect the line with "Domain" keyword

Comment: @Mwthreex Not sure what you mean, share your regex string.

Comment: @Mwthreex No idea what you mean. `Domain` is not in the contents you shared. Share the regex fiddle.

Comment: 1
00:00:39,243 --> 00:00:45,820
This line should detected with 'Domain' keyword but it does not
www.Domain.com

Just replace Ads or Download with 'Domain' in your regex

https://i.imgur.com/qt2Y1FI.png

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew i'm wasting your time nevermind, Your regex works but it doesnt detect some keywords i figure it out by myself thank you

Comment: @Mwthreex It [works](https://regex101.com/r/xVFlfd/4) on my end